# Passing a parameter on React Dialog from OnClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dialog, material-ui

I am fairly new to React.js and I'm currently trying to pass parameters on my dialog from onclicks.

```
       <IconButton className={classes.approvebutton} onClick={() => handleDialogClick("approve",1)}> 
          <ThumbUp />
       </IconButton>
       <IconButton className={classes.rejectbutton} onClick={() => handleDialogClick("reject",1)} >
          <ThumbDown />
       </IconButton>
```

as for the onclick function:

```
  function handleDialogClick (approvalType,id){
alert(`hello, ${approvalType}`);
switch(approvalType) {
  case 1:
    setDialogOpen(true);

    break;
  case 2:
    setDialogOpen(true);
    break;
  default:
    setDialogOpen(true);
}}
```

What I would like is for the approval type and id be passed on inside the Dialog:

```
<Dialog onClose={handleDialogApproveClose} aria-labelledby="simple-dialog-title" open={dialogOpen}>
          <DialogTitle id="simple-dialog-title">Request Approval</DialogTitle>
          <DialogContent>
            <DialogContentText id="alert-dialog-description">
              Do you want to //approvalType goes here//  this request?
            </DialogContentText>          
          </DialogContent>
          <DialogActions>
            <Button onClick={handleClose} color="primary">
              No
            </Button>
            <Button onClick={() => submitAction(// id goes here)} color="primary" autoFocus>
              Yes
            </Button>
          </DialogActions>
        </Dialog>
```

*All of the code is under a single component.*

I tried looking into google but I am confused on how to implement it on my code.

Comment: Where are <IconButton> components located? The question is a bit unclear, do you want handleDialogClick to be called on onClick of <Button>?

Comment: What issue are you facing? Is there an error? Unexpected results?

Comment: Your cases don't really make sense, should they not be `"approve"` and `"reject"`?

Comment: @BrianThompson yes they should be. I'll edit the question and add the other items I'm lacking to better understand the problem. sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `handleDialogClick` is working incorrectly. In your switch case, you are using `approvalType` to check the condition but in each case, you are using `id` to open or close your dialog `setDialogOpen`. 
If you want to use `approvalType` to setDialogOpen, the code should be:

```js
function handleDialogClick (approvalType,id){
  alert(`hello, ${approvalType}`);
  switch(approvalType) {
    case 'approve':
      setDialogOpen(true);
      break;
    case 'reject':
      setDialogOpen(true);
      break;
    default:
      setDialogOpen(true);
}}
```

If you want to use id to setDialogOpen, the code should be:

```js
function handleDialogClick (approvalType,id){
  alert(`hello, ${approvalType}`);
  switch(id) {
    case 1:
      setDialogOpen(true);
      break;
    case 2:
      setDialogOpen(true);
      break;
    default:
      setDialogOpen(true);
}}
```